# Problems with CSS Grid creating a simple CSS layout with rows and multiple divs centered

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am a beginner with CSS Grid and wanted to create a simple CSS layout for my personal blog. I am trying it out within codepen.io

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/ybog/pen/rGVaWa)

What i want to achieve is to have multiple rows which have full width and within those rows to have additional divs with different widths and centered in the parent (row), maybe also more than one cause i need to have lets say 10 divs from top to down in one row. But i am stuck and it is not working. I have created a small image of what i am looking for. (link at the bottom)

This is my HMTL:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box menu">Menu with full width and elements in it</div>
  <div class="box header">Header with full with, but i cannot change the color on the full width background and have for the inner box a different color</div>
  <div class="box posts">Posts coming here   ... </div>
  <div class="box posts">
    <div class="post_small_width">smaller</div>
    <div class="post_medium_width">wider</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box pages">Pages, normally here should be a container inside which has not full width, maybe 900px and centered within this div</div>
  <div class="box footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

And this the CSS:

```
* {
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "menu"
    "header"
    "posts"
    "post_small_width"
    "post_medium_width"
    "pages"
    "footer"
  ;

  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  background-color: #444;
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

.posts {
  margin:auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: posts;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pages {
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-area: pages;
}

.post_small_width {
  background-color: #red;
  grid-area: post_small_width;
}

.post_medium_width {
  background-color: #red;
  grid-area: post_medium_width;
}

.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-area: footer;
}

.box {

}
```

This is image:
[Sample Layout for visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBUag.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve: https://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/pWJPdN

You need to better understand how to structure the DOM.
Read up on responsive design. You want to give a set width to your parent containers for some reason. What you should rather do is have an equal max-width for your parent containers and have your content inside them.

```
.parent-container {
   max-width: 900px;
   width: 100%
   margin: auto;
 }
```